# Combining two List<T> together, merging instances of T based on instance member using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, join

I have an abstract class called NamedEntity (that is overridden by various different sub classes):

```
public abstract class NamedEntity<T> where T : TweetModel
{
    protected string _name;
    public abstract string Name { get; set; }
    public abstract List<TweetModel> tweets { get; set; }
}
```

The key element in this class is the `List<TweetModel>` which contains a list of Tweet objects, designed to model the basic metadata associated with a Tweet (i.e. text, author, date/time etc).

How can I combine two `List<NamedEntity<TweetModel>>` so that items from one list are amalgamated into the other list based on matching value for the Name property?

I.e. NamedEntity1 has the name "London" + associated tweets **and** NamedEntity2 also has the name "London" and a different `List<TweetModel>`. How can I merge these two, in turn pulling the `List<TweetModel>` instances from both collections and adding them to the new `List<NamedEntity<TweetModel>>` object?

I've read that I can use a join here, but I don't really understand the LINQ syntax:

```
private List<NamedEntity<TweetModel>> joinLists(List<NamedEntity<TweetModel>> list1, List<NamedEntity<TweetModel>> list2)
{
    //var joined = from Name in list1 join Name in list2 on ????;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 things you need to tell `Join`: Which collections to join, join them by what and how to actually join them:

```
private IEnumerable<NamedEntity<TweetModel>> Join(
    IEnumerable<NamedEntity<TweetModel>> list1,
    IEnumerable<NamedEntity<TweetModel>> list2)
{
    return list1.Join(list2, item => item.Name, item => item.Name, (outer, inner) =>
    {
        outer.tweets.AddRange(inner.tweets);
        return outer;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Union()` to combine both `List<NamedEntity<TweetModel>>`, group them by `Name`, and select new object with `tweets` property populated with combination of all `tweets` in the corresponding group :

```
private List<NamedEntity<TweetModel>> joinLists(List<NamedEntity<TweetModel>> list1, List<NamedEntity<TweetModel>> list2)
{
    List<NamedEntity<TweetModel>> joined;

    joined = list1.Union(list2)
                  .GroupBy(o => o.Name)
                  .Select(o => new NamedEntity<TweetModel>
                                 {
                                     Name = o.Key,
                                     tweets =
                                         o.SelectMany(x => x.tweets).ToList()
                                 }).ToList();

    return joined;
}
```

This way you can avoid losing some `NamedEntity<TweetModel>`s in a situation, for example, when `NamedEntity1` & `NamedEntity2` in your example are in the same `List<T>`. With a plain LINQ join (since it is basically an INNER JOIN), only `NamedEntity<TweetModel>`s having `Name` exist in both lists will be returned.

Comment: How would I get around the issue here that I cannot create an instance of the (abstract) NamedEntity class in the `.Select` expression?

Answer (score 1):

You always have the option of just using nested traditional foreach loops. You could even create an extension method that can merge your 2 lists:

```
public static class NamedEntityExtensions
{
    public static IList<NamedEntity<T>> MergeEntities<T>(this IList<NamedEntity<T>> list1, IList<NamedEntity<T>> list2)
        where T: TweetModel
    {
        foreach(NamedEntity<T> entity1 in list1)
        {
            foreach(NamedEntity<T> entity2 in list2)
            {
                if(entity1.Name == entity2.Name)
                {
                    entity1.Tweets.AddRange(entity2.Tweets);
                }
            }
        }

        return list1; //original list will get augmented but returning it allows chaining
    }
}
```

You can then merge using something like this:

```
list1.MergeEntities(list2);
```

This method also supports chaining calls to more than 2 lists:

```
list1.MergeEntities(list2).MergeEntities(list3);
```

If you don't want to actually modify the original list1, you can always produce a new list inside of the extension method instead of adding to the original.

NOTE: This will only work if list1 contains all of the distinct "Name" values that you care about. Additional logic would need to be added to create new items from entities that only exist in list 2.